# Access other entities while creating a Doctrine entity

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine

Say I have tables A, B in MySQL and Doctrine entity classes with the same names. Those entities are managed by Doctrine and are basically created according to Symfony/Doctrine docs.

Now I want to create entity C with columns: x, y. Whenever this entity is created or updated, I want to set the column values:

- x: select count(*) from A where (some condition)
- y: select sum(y) from B where (other condition)
- pull some other data from A or B and store it as column value for C.

I want to do this in PHP and not use mysql triggers. I can't achieve from inside the Entity classes, because they don't have access to entity manager. I don't want to do this in the controller, as I want insert/update operations to be standardized, and I will need to do it from multiple controllers, and I generally don't think the controller is a good place for logic like this.

So I need some kind of class which manages entity C.

My question is: How do I call this manager class and where do I place it in Symfony? I am pretty sure this is a common need in Symfony (to access multiple entities while creating another entity), but I don't know how it is called and if there is a standard practice with them.

Comment: use DirectInjection component (DI) to create  *service* - inject doctrine.entitymanager service into it and access all the repositories as needed.

Comment: Did you mean Dependency Injection? Honestly, I have a feeling doctrine entities are unaware of entity manager for a reason.

Comment: You probably want a doctrine listener: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events Just be aware the it can be a bit challenging to keep these sort of things in sync.  Only go this route if you really feel like you can't calculate the necessary information on the fly.

Comment: @cerad Yes, I have been looking into that lately and it probably is closest to what I need. Can you elaborate more on *it can be a bit challenging to keep these sort of things in sync* ? This feature looks really promising and simple, but maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, it can be challenging to trigger and catch all the desired events.  Sometimes it works great.  Other times, not so much.

Comment: I think that you just need some service. Check @b3da answer. Doctrine events can be to much for your needs (and to complex/complicated).

Comment: @Karolis - yes, I misspoke and meant DependencyInjection. I wasn't meaning to imply to inject the entity manager into the entity. I meant create a service and inject the entity manager there, then do the work as needed from within the custom service.

Comment: Well, an entity listener is a service. It is standardized, documented and has a clear meaning. I could invent some custom service and inject the entity manager, but that is not the purpose. The purpose is to create a pattern that is easy to understand and is common in symfony framework. I am learning the framework  in order  not to have to reinvent the wheel. So far I find the answer from @Cerad closest to what I was looking for. If he posts an answer, I will accept it (unless better ideas are given) :)

Comment: It all depends on the requirements.  I understood the question to mean that you wanted entity C to be kept in sync with A and B.  In other words, changes to A and B would trigger changes to C.  This is the sort of thing that listeners are good for.  If it is more of a one shot deal where C is built by the current state of A and B then a simple service as described below is the way to go.  I'd suggest trying both approaches to see which fits best.

Answer (score 2):

you can define service in app/config/services.yml and pass Entity manager as argument

```
services:
    app.service.some_service:
        class: AppBundle\Service\SomeService
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]
```

place your logic inside service

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\SomeEntity;

class SomeService
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getSomeEntity($id) {
        $entity = $this->entityManager->getRepository(SomeEntity::class);
        // do some work, return result..

    }
}
```

call it from controller

```
$someService = $this->get('app.service.some_service');
$someService->getSomeEntity($id);
```

:)

Comment: this is basically what I was trying to (poorly) say, above.

Comment: The issue of this solution is `AppBundle\Service\SomeService `. What I have described in the question is a common (standard) task, and `SomeService` is not a standard solution.  Nobody knows what the service does just by looking at the name. In case of an entity listener, i find it more clear.

Comment: @Karolis I believe that creating custom service for whatever task more complex than updating one value (for which are LifecycleCallbacks better solution) is a standard solution, imho. that way you can have all logic - bind to some operation with multiple entities - in one place. btw, SomeService is just placeholder for your more descriptive service name, so 'nobody knows..' is not problem at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a Doctrine Event Subscriber as [described in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

I'll try to explain the basics.

1) Declare the service

```
services:
  c_entity_counter_subscriber:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\CounterSubscriber
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

2) In the Subscriber count A and B properties

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\A;
use AppBundle\Entity\B;
use AppBundle\Entity\C;

class CounterSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
  public function getSubscribedEvents()
  {
    return array(
        'postPersist',
        'postUpdate',
    );
  }

  public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
  {
    $this->count($args);
  }

  public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
  {
    $this->count($args);
  }

  public function count(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
  {

    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if (!$entity instanceof C) {
      return;
    }

    $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
    // ... count/sum entities from A/B classes using $entityManager and update $entity
  }
}
```

Comment: In case A, B and/or C data are retrieved from different connections maybe you'll need to inject 'doctrine' in service definition.

Comment: What about performance? If I have subscribed to postPersist/postUpdate events, can this also affect entity loading/hydration  (just because there is a listener that needs to be loaded) ?

Comment: There should no exists performance degradation in listener/subscriber declaration and loading. And, as you check `$entity` is instance of 'C' the subscriber will return fast.

Comment: And reading from db, count and sum entities in A/B will be far more time consuming.